# PHP array avoid Undefined offset

Tags: php, arrays, crosstab

Hi I have array like this

```
$subject_names[7]="English";
$subject_names[11]="Software Engeneering";

//Student can choose multiple subjects and each subject have int_mark and ext_mark

$results['Matt'][7]['int_mark'] =15;
$results['Matt'][7]['ext_mark'] =55;

$results['Josh'][7]['int_mark'] =12;
$results['Josh'][7]['ext_mark'] =45;
$results['Josh'][11]['int_mark'] =14;
$results['Josh'][11]['ext_mark'] = 52;

// the array is to maintain crosstab format
```

And to print this I did

```
echo "Student Name\t";

foreach($subject_names as $subject_name)
{
    echo "$subject_name\t";
}
echo "<br>";

foreach ($results as $student_name => $subjects) 
{
    echo "$student_name\t";

    foreach($subject_names as $subject_id => $sub_name){

        foreach ($subjects[$subject_id] as $mark){ 
             echo "$mark\t";
        }

    }
    echo "<br>";

}
```

As Student "Matt" doesn't has subject_id 11 It is giving me a error notice

> Notice: Undefined offset: 11

How do I Ignore it and print N/A if the Student have not that subject

Thank you for your any help and suggestions

Comment: before print check `if(isset($array[$offset]))`

Comment: My bad , So funny How did I Ignore this THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isset()` along with `count()`:-

```
if(isset($subjects[$subject_id]) && count($subjects[$subject_id])>0){
    foreach ($subjects[$subject_id] as $mark){ 
       echo "$mark\t";
    }
}
```

You can use `!empty()` with `count()` check too:-

```
if(!empty($subjects[$subject_id]) && count($subjects[$subject_id])>0){
    foreach ($subjects[$subject_id] as $mark){ 
       echo "$mark\t";
    }
}
```

Comment: @sanu  `count()` is added so that if array have no value then iteration part will stop. if array is empty then also iteration part goes on(at-least one time) in case of `isset()` only.

Comment: Yes Thanks Your answer is more clear So I will Accept this answer

Comment: @sanu  glad to help you.Cheers :):):)